# How to Set Active Menu Using Database And Bootstrap

Tags: php

I have problems with my application . so I make a dynamically menu using the database . and the problem is when I click on the dropdown menu and I choose its dropdown menu . then the menu is not active set

i follow the example of

> http://harviacode.com/2014/10/25/mengatur-aktif-menu-bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Faizal3696</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <?php
                    $base = '?page=';
                    $route = $_GET['page']?$_GET['page']:'home';

                    $menu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY menu_id ASC");

                    while($dataMenu = mysql_fetch_assoc($menu)){
                        $menu_id = $dataMenu['menu_id'];
                        $submenu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE menu_id='$menu_id' ORDER BY submenu_id ASC");   

                        if(mysql_num_rows($submenu) == 0){
            $active = $route==$dataMenu['menu_link']?' class="active"':'';

                            echo '<li'.$active.'><a href="'.$base.$dataMenu['menu_link'].'">'.$dataMenu['menu'].'</a></li>';

                        }else{

                            echo '<li'.$active.'>
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">'.$dataMenu['menu'].' <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';
                                            while($dataSubmenu = mysql_fetch_assoc($submenu)){
                                                echo '<li><a href="'.$base.$dataSubmenu['submenu_link'].'">'.$dataSubmenu['submenu'].'</a></li>';
                                            }
                            echo '      </ul>
                                   </li>';
                        }
                    }       
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container" role="main" style="min-height:535px;width: 100%" >

<div class="col-sm-3" style=""> 
    <h2>Navigation</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="width:250px">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="list-group">
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#"> Beta Version</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#"> Beta Version</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#"> Beta Version</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#"> Beta Version</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#"> Beta Version</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#"> Beta Version</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#"> Beta Version</a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#"> Beta Version</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        include $_GET['page'].'.php';
    }  else {// kondisi ketika site pertama di load
        include 'home.php';
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why dont you try wordpress walker for nav menu??

Comment: Indrasinh Bihola wordpress walker? what is?.

Comment: Check wordpress built in theme they are providing builtin function named wp_nav_menu for dynamic navigation menu.